# Create an appointment in someone email id in outlook calendar with C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a Visual Studio 2022 program which makes it possible to create an appointment in someone else's Outlook calendar.

For example: if someone asks to create an appointment in someone else's Outlook calendar. I already made some code in which allows you to set your own appointments.

Here is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S579t.png)

```
public async Task<bool> CreateAppointmentAsync()
{
    var spinId = Guid.NewGuid();
    StringBuilder apptBody = new StringBuilder();
    var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
    bool success = false;
    var username = _employee.Email;

    try
    {
        string ewsUrl = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
       
        ExchangeService servicex = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        servicex.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        servicex.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user@domain.com", "password");
        servicex.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl);
        servicex.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress,   "user@domain.com");

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(servicex);
        // Set the properties on the appointment object to create the appointment.
        appointment.Subject = "Tennis lesson";
        appointment.Body = "Focus on backhand this week.";
        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
        appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(1);
        appointment.Location = "Tennis club";
        appointment.ReminderDueBy = DateTime.Now;
        appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);

        Item item = await Item.Bind(servicex, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject));

        success = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Event Created");
        Console.WriteLine("Subject of the retrieved appointment: " + item.Subject);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return success;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Stop spinner
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseControlEvent>().Publish(spinId.ToString());
    }
    return success;
}
```

However, I get an error:

> "Appointment.id" Value cannot be null (Parameter 'itemId')

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Make sure the appointment is saved successfully after creating it by checking if `appointment.Id` is not null before attempting to bind and retrieve the item.

Comment: i will try and update at same time issues occurred .appointment.Id Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'itemId') ,specific this line  Item item = await Item.Bind(servicex, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject));
 MessageBox.Show("Successfully Event Created");
 success = true;

Comment: It seems that the appointment you are creating might not be getting an ID assigned before you attempt to bind it to an `Item`.

Comment: Load the appointment after it's saved using `appointment.Load()` to ensure the `appointment.Id` is refreshed with the correct value.

Comment: Yes this method i try it appointment.Load() same issues are replicated. if appointment.id is null

Comment: if any idea appointment.Id value cannot be null

Comment: If the `appointment.Id` is still null even after calling `appointment.Load()`, it might indicate an issue with the way the appointment is being created or saved.

Comment: how to getting and assign appointment .id

Comment: appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
   appointment.Load();  i just try it but appoinment.id still null value

Comment: appointment.Load(); i just included this method,
  'This operation can't be performed because this service object doesn't have an Id=>this error occurred.

Comment: I Used Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data